# Remove HTML nodes from HTTP Request

Tags: c#, html

I have some HTML code stored into a string variable, resulting from a `HttpWebRequest`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <div>Lots of scripts and libraries</div>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Some very useful data</div>
  </body>
  <footer>
    <div>Not interesting struff</div>
  </footer>
<html>
```

How can I do to remove all unecesary nodes and get into this:

```
<body>
  <div>Some very useful data</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `HtmlAgilityPack` to grab just the `body` tag.

```
var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);

HtmlNode body = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
```

From there, you can use `HtmlAgilityPack` to further parse the `body` node for more detail.

Comment: I'd add "best" along with "easiest" way. Parsing html by hand is tougher than it looks.

Comment: Great solution! Now I have what I wanted. Also, this quick tutorial complemenets Robert's answer: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp